# C++ | How to prevent my code from essentially increasing the value of my integers/values?

Tags: c++, variables, calculator, calculation

Just in case the title wasn't descriptive enough, I wrote a basic calculator as a beginner and after random stress-testing and experimenting trying to find bugs, I found something that results in the following as an example.

> Would you like to add, subtract, multiply, divide, or use powers? (A,S,M,D,P)
> D
> What integer would you like to start with?
> 48834343
> What would you like to divide 48834343 by?
> 34923499234
> 48834343 divided by 3.49235e+10 is equal to 0.00139832

The code is somehow shifting the decimal over or just multiplying it by a random multiple of 10. I have tried using different variable types which seemed to fix it a little bit but when you start increasing the character count of the number(s), the more it seems to break with most variable types. I'm probably missing something since I'm a beginner, so don't hold anything back in any explanation as far as criticism goes, but please ELI5.

Enough chitchat, here's the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

void add() {
    cout << "What integer would you like to start with?\n";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "What would you like to add to " << x << "?\n";
    int y;
    cin >> y;
    cout << x << " plus " << y << " is equal to " << x + y;
}

void subt() {
    cout << "What integer would you like to start with?\n";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "What would you like to subtract from " << x << "?\n";
    int y;
    cin >> y;
    cout << x << " minus " << y << " is equal to " << x - y;
}

void mult() {
    cout << "What integer would you like to start with?\n";
    double x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "What would you like to multiply " << x << " by?\n";
    double y;
    cin >> y;
    cout << x << " times " << y << " is equal to " << x * y;
}

void divd() {
    cout << "What integer would you like to start with?\n";
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "What would you like to divide " << x << " by?\n";
    float y;
    cin >> y;
    cout << x << " divided by " << y << " is equal to " << x / y;
}

void power() {
    cout << "What integer would you like to start with?\n";
    long double x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << x << " to the power of what?\n";
    long double y;
    cin >> y;
    cout << x << " to the power of " << y << " is equal to " << pow(x, y);
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Would you like to add, subtract, multiply, divide, or use powers? (A,S,M,D,P)";
    string ans;
    cin >> ans;
    //user responds with the first letter of the operation they want
    if (ans == "A") {
        add();
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ans == "S") {
        subt();
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ans == "M") {
        mult();
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ans == "D") {
        divd();
        return 0;
    }
    else if (ans == "P") {
        power();
        return 0;
    }
    else cout << "Error, try again with one of the above letters";
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: It's using _scientific notation_ to represent the value.  If you want to use fixed-point, use the I/O manipulator `std::fixed`: _i.e._ `std::cout << std::fixed`.  You may need to include `<iomanip>`.

Comment: Should be said that this might cause other headaches, because it uses fixed precision (via `std::setprecision`) which you have to decide.  Also, what if you have the value 1e-100?  Do you _really_ want to print out `0.00000000000000000 ........  01`?  What about 1e100?  You wanna show the entire number?  My pocket calculator from the 90s doesn't do that.

Comment: *"Just in case the title wasn't descriptive enough"* -- please assume this. A question's title should summarize the issue, and the opening paragraph should expand on it (c.f. [ask]). People who assume that their title is descriptive enough tend to have poorly written questions. Don't fall into that trap.

Comment: *"a random multiple of 10"* -- not so random. How many digits are to the left of the decimal point? Does this ever vary? Does the number after the `e` (short for exponent) always correspond to the power of 10 involved?